# Global exception handler middleware in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core

Context:
I'm trying to find a way to add a global exception handler middleware in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 Webapi that can catch any unhandled exceptions, log them and return a ProblemDetails response.

This is what I've got so far in my Startup.cs: (only including the relevant code)

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
    {
        ExceptionHandler = ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler
    });
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}

private async Task ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler(HttpContext context)
{
    var requestServiceProvider = context.RequestServices;
    var problemDetailsFactory = requestServiceProvider?.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
    if (problemDetailsFactory == null) return;

    if (context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        // Log
        return;
    }

    var problemDetails = problemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(context,
        StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
        detail: "An error occurred");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", new StringValues("application/problem+json"));
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(problemDetails), Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

What I'm after:

1. How do I access the exception object to log the details?
2. In my exception handler delegate (ProblemDetailsExceptionHandler) do I need to check if response has started?
3. I would also like to catch a 404 and return a ProblemDetails response. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using Filters instead of Middleware? In such a case you could derive from `ExceptionFilterAttribute` and things might be a bit easier for you

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you should look at [Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails) which already provides this feature. Also, there is [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.0) for error handling in ASP.NET Core Web APIs.

Comment: Thanks @cremor. I've used Hellang.Middleware with my aspnet core 2.2 projects but I believe 3.0 was supposed to have the functionality out of the box? I'll take a look at ms docs

Comment: Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails is still very useful with ASP.NET Core 3.0. There are still things missing, e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4953

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom exception filter attribute, like this

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // if you want to do something special with specific exceptions type
        if (context.Exception is TypeOfException)
        {
            // do something custom
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            context.Result = new JsonResult(
                ((ValidationException)context.Exception).Failures);

            return;
        }



        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new
        {
            error = new[] { context.Exception.Message },
            stackTrace = context.Exception.StackTrace
        });
    }
}
```

Then register it in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilterAttribute)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for this approach. My use case is web apis that must return a ProblemDetails response.

Comment: You can use this in Web API, `error = new[] { context.Exception.Message },` is bascially returning the problem detail.

Comment: Thanks again, I could get the exception in my middleware by using  context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>(). Since either that middleware or this filter gets executed when there is an exception, I cannot catch 404s